# Joining table with large data and performance

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table called `tblRewards` which has data around 300 rows and it has columns UserId, AwardDate,  RewarTypedId etc, I have another table called `tblUser` which can have almost 100 000 of Users data.

I would like to get data like UserId, AwardDate, Pincode, SegmentId, IsActive  with a query.

My query is like below.

```
SELECT r.UserId, r.AwardDate, u.Pincode, u.SegmentId, u.IsActive 
FROM dbo.tblRewards r
INNER JOIN tblUser u ON r.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE r.RewardTypeId = 123 AND u.SegmentId = 123
```

My issue is regarding performance, my `tblRewards` table has only few hundred records but the `tblUser` table has several hundred thousand records and it keeps increasing every day, now when I join this it keeps comparing with every row and there can be performance hit.

I am just looking if there is any way to overcome this and write this in an efficient way with good performance.

Comment: Tip: its considered best practice to name all tables as either singular or plural... but not to mix it up as you have done.

Comment: Dale K Good suggestion Dale, Thank you.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical.) Please research before considering posting. That includes basics of SQL optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `tblUser` table has many more records than `tblRewards`, you should consider indexing the former table to avoid SQL Server having to scan this table.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_reward ON tblRewards (RewardTypeId, UserId) INCLUDE (AwardDate);
```

If used, SQL Server would be scanning the user table, and then using the above index for the join lookup.  Note that the above index completely covers the entire query on `tblRewards`.

Comment: So that is going to be a non clustered Index right ?